# Netify deployment site showing the blank page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In the local host and GitHub pages, my React App is working fine and then, when I upload my build folder into the deploy manually or deploy from GitHub, it shows a blank white page and some errors in the console. Help me to publish my site through the netify.
link: https://dreamy-kitsune-263c9c.netlify.app/
My git hub page link: https://likithkandepu13.github.io/attendance/
[Errors in the console as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNz7X.png)